# "I really need some moving on here" - is it correct to say like this?

Tags: phrase-requests

How correct it is to say "I really need some moving on here"?

Say, you are posting a question on an internet forum, or opening a discussion thread, and want people on forum to get involved in answering or discussing. Having many people involved doesn't necessarily imply a quick answer to the question posted or an immediate clarification and development of the subject matter, thus, I would refrain from saying "I really need some progress here". "I really need some moving on here" kind of appeals to me, but I am not sure how correct it is. Google gives only 6 results.

Comment: Native speakers wouldn't have a problem with *"I really need some progress here"*. I don't see why OP isn't happy with that, and I don't see the point of asking for paraphrasings that he/we might consider "better".

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Why wouldn't you talk to me directly instead of using the third-person "OP"? Is it polite in English speaking world to act like this? Perhaps, it is okay to act in this way in the English speaking world (there  reason why I am asking is because in my culture it would be quite rude).

Comment: @FumbleFingers - "I don't see the point of asking for paraphrasings that he/we might consider "better"" - That's the whole point - I don't know which way is better. That's why I asked this question.

Comment: I certainly didn't mean to offend you, so I'm sorry for that. But you must realise that I'm addressing an unknown number of people as I write, not you in particular. Obviously this specific comment is directed at *you*, so I'm using that pronoun. But if a dozen people are reading the earlier comment, and you are only one of them, *"OP"* seems by convention to be the best way of referring to you. Regarding your second point - why would you not be happy to use the same phrases native speakers use? It just makes no sense.

Comment: @FumbleFingers "I certainly didn't mean to offend you, so I'm sorry for that" - That's okay, I am not offended, I just wanted to know the reasons why you acted in that way. I was a bit confused by this practice because I saw people do that here and there and in my culture that kind of thing would bridge on insult. As I see now, it's a common practice in English speaking environment and is not meant to be offensive.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - "Regarding your second point - why would you not be happy to use the same phrases native speakers use?" - Because I simply wasn't sure that those phrases meant exactly what I meant to say. I think I explained that clearly in my question. You see, you, being a native speaker, think it is just damn obvious to use those phrases in that case, but to me, as to a non-native speaker, it is not so obvious at all!

Comment: That's okay then. But I'm not sure this usage of *"OP"* can be meaningfully called *"common practice in [an] English speaking environment"*. If you know French you might like to ask on their **meta** how [French Language & Usage](http://french.stackexchange.com/) contributors refer to the "Original Poster". I think it's a site-specific usage, not really related to the fact that we speak English.

Comment: Regarding my second point. You give two possible phrasings - one perfectly common (which for some reason you don't want to use), and one of your own devising (for no obvious reason), that sounds completely unnatural to native speakers. Why not just stick with the common one, which presumably you must have come across before?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4505/discussion-between-brilliant-and-fumblefingers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase *moving on* generally means *leaving an issue/person behind*, such as in the song titled I'm [Movin' On](http://www.cowboylyrics.com/lyrics/classic-country/im-movin-on---hank-snow-14935.html) by Hank Snow (also sung by Bob Dylan). It does not convey what you want.

The phrase *move on* something might convey what you want.

> I need to *move on* this.

Perhaps the this sentence might work better.

> I need some action on this.

or

> I need to take some action on this.

Comment: To the extent that *"to move **on**"* is a "phrasal verb" in the first place, it's totally irrelevant to OP's usage.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - But as a transitive verb, the phrase *move on* something is used regularly in business to indicat the need to take action. I agree that as an intransitive phrasal verb it means something else and not what OP wants. Because of the ambiguity, I suggested *need . . .action* or *take . . . action*.

Comment: Your first paragraph is still irrelevant. Why mention something which as you say *"does not convey what [OP] wants"*? He never raised that usage.

Comment: He asked whether "I really need some *moving on*" was correct to convey what he wants. I answered why it was not.

Comment: Well, I don't want to keep on. It's not much of a question in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

If you're actually asking more of a general question on how to provoke the greatest response, i.e. taking the question literally. The hard sell and posturing demands are counter effective. Make your post as interesting as possible and well worded. Then invite responses in closing. If I read a post that says at the end "I need to move on this" or other demands, I'd be much less likely to participate. "I welcome everyone's thoughts on this" is still a little contrived when posted on a forum, as it is implied. It is much better form than demands to meet your own needs.